# Evaluation of a data set with conditional selection of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I want to evaluate a data set with precipitation data. The data is available as a csv file, which I have read in with pandas as dataframe. From this then follows the following table:

```
year  month  day      value
0      1981      1    1   0.522592
1      1981      1    2   2.692495
2      1981      1    3   0.556698
3      1981      1    4   0.000000
4      1981      1    5   0.000000
...     ...    ...  ...        ...
43824  2100     12   27   0.000000
43825  2100     12   28   0.185120
43826  2100     12   29  10.252080
43827  2100     12   30  13.389290
43828  2100     12   31   3.523566
```

Now I want to convert the daily precipitation values into monthly precipitation values and that for each month (for this I would need the sum of each day of a month). For this I probably need a loop or something similar. However, I do not know how to proceed. Maybe via a conditional selection over 'year' and 'month'?!
I would be very happy about feedback! :)

That´s what I tried now:

```
for i in range(len(dataframe)):
    print(dataframe.loc[i, 'year'], dataframe.loc[i, 'month'])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: please provide a data sample (enough to perform simple computations) as **text**, not image

Comment: @thomas.f please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72062035/edit) the question to format the data in a clean way

Comment: @mozway I edited my original question, didn't know how to do that in the comment, sorry

Comment: @JoshClark I tried this once, but does not provide the desired selection... am still very new to python and therefore unfortunately do not understand it so well. I edited my question with a code i tried :)

Comment: Looks like you need to be doing some addition somewhere. Right now you're just printing "year" and "month." If you want to get the sum of each month's daily value, you need to keep a sum and loop over the rows, adding values whose rows share the same month value.

Comment: @JoshClark yes, that's right. Unfortunately, I don't know how best to start. The connection between summing and the loop I do not get... i also don't know how to add the condition with the same month value in the loop....

Comment: Yikes, looping in a pandas DataFrame is rarely the correct approach. `Groupby` could be used at worst, but for time data formatted nicely like this, `Resample` is far more robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start out by making a single column with the date:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])
```

From here you can make the date the index:

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
# I'll drop the unneeded year, month, and day columns as well.
df = df[['value']]
```

My data now looks like:

```
               value
date
1981-01-01  0.522592
1981-01-02  2.692495
1981-01-03  0.556698
1981-01-04  0.000000
1981-01-05  0.000000
```

From here, let's try [resampling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) the data!

```
# let's doing a 2 day sum. To do monthly, you'd replace '2d' with 'M'.
df.resample('2d').sum()
```

Output:

```
               value
date
1981-01-01  3.215087
1981-01-03  0.556698
1981-01-05  0.000000
```

Hopefully this gives you something to start with~

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed answer. worked as I imagined :)

Comment: Now I am faced with the next problem. I want to average the monthly values again over the meteorological months, i.e. December+January+February, March+April+May and so on. How do I get this done? At the moment, that's all I can manage:

` df_meteo_months = df_monthly.resample('3M').sum() `

So here three months are added together, but not the meteorological months..

Comment: Sounds like a question worthy of making a new post! Please mark this as the accepted answer if you feel like it sufficiently answered your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried groupby?

```
Df.groupby(['year', 'month'])['value'].agg('sum')
```